# Merging two sorted list in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

How do i get this code to work,
I am trying to merge this two list together in a sorted form;

example:

LIST = 3,8,16,28,50,17,19,30,73,80

where 3,8,16,28,50 right hand side
and   17,19,30,73,80 left hand side
contained in the same list but approached as two different lists.

This is My code:

```
int main()
{
    int first,last,m,temp, counter = 0,lsize = 11;
    int a[lsize] = {3,8,16,28,50,17,19,30,73,80};

    for(int i = 0 ; i < lsize; i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ,";
    cout<<"\n";

    first = 0;
    last = lsize;
    m = (first + last) / 2;
    int i = 0;
    while(counter < lsize){

        if(a[first] < a[m+1] && m+1 < last ){
            counter++;first++;
        }
        else if(a[m+1] < a[first] && first <= m){
            temp = a[m+1];
            shift(a,first,m+1);
            a[counter]=temp;
            counter++;first++;m++;
        }
        else if(m+1 > last && first <= m){
            a[counter]=a[first];
            first++;counter++;
        }
        else if(first > m && m+1 <= last){
            a[counter]=a[m+1];
            m++;counter++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < lsize; i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ,";
    cout<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this as output

3,8,16,17,19,28,30,50,65,73,73

Hope somebody can help me point out where am getting it wrong
Thanks

Comment: Have you look at `std::inplace_merge` ?

Comment: How are you getting a 65 in your output? Are you sure the code you posted matches the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STL is there to help avoid errors and wasting time debugging common algorithms such as this.

```
std::vector<int> listA {3,8,16,28,50};
std::vector<int> listB {17,19,30,73,80};
std::vector<int> result;
std::merge(listA.begin(), listA.end(), listB.begin(), listB.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
```

Or as Jarod42 points out, you can do it in place with

```
std::vector<int> listA {3,8,16,28,50,17,19,30,73,80};
std::inplace_merge(listA, listA.begin()+5, listA.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 elements in your list (lsize), however are looping 11 times in your print statement (0 to lsize-1).

Answer (score 0):

With `<algorithm>`, you may do

```
std::inplace_merge(std::begin(a), a + 5, std::end(a)); // a+5 is for 17.
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/TY6sib)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys !!
I also found out that the if(condition) and  first if else(condition) were missing a condition as follows:

```
 if(a[first] < a[m+1] && m+1 <= last && first <= m )
```

and

```
else if(a[m+1] < a[first] && first <= m && m+1 <= last)
```

that is a third condition from each.

Answer (score -1):

C++ does not allow variable sized list. So, you should get an error in second line of your code.I don't know how it's working for you. Secondly, lsize should be 10 instead of 11.

Comment: Thanks, for the observation I missed a 65 in the list. It should have been                  LIST[lsize] = {3,8,16,28,50,17,19,30,65,73,80} where lsize = 11;